# Retroarch not showing after installing using Flatpak on Elementary OS

Tags: software-installation

I'm very inexperienced with Linux, so I'll try to explain what I did:

I allowed elementary OS to install flatpak by typing this:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Then I installed Flatpak (which is apparently useful to install retroarch):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Then I installed retroarch with the command provided on their website:

```
flatpak install --user flathub org.libretro.RetroArch
```

After receiving the packets, I've been searching everywhere and there are no files named retroarch, libretro or flatpak on my computer so I'm lost.

Comment: Ok. It seems I can download retroarch without Flatpak now that I entered the **sudo apt-get install software-properties-common** command, I should have tried that earlier. Now I'll try to find a way to remove the files that flatpak downloaded and kept hidden. I'm not sure why Flatpak was so recommended, I only had trouble using it and I fail to see the advantages. If some people are also having trouble installing retroarch on ElementaryOS just type **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libretro/stable && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install retroarch** and you should be set.

Comment: It seems impossible to install a core (emulator) inside the retroarch's version of linux, you need to do it manually in the terminal and know the specific name of the emulator you are searching. Then it gets more fun as you need to manually set up the path to the libraries individually in a retroarch.cfg file. All those things are done automatically in the Windows version of retroarch and it just works instantly. I'll just give it up and return to windows. Not sure if url are permited but you'll need this if you have the courage to go on: http://emulation-general.wikia.com/wiki/Using_RetroArch